# WPF Caliburn.Micro DataGrid columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF Caliburn.Micro application that has a tab control with a DataGrid in it. The columns in the DataGrid are set programmatically. I may need to close a tab, and then open it again. And I get an exception, saying a column already exists in the DataGrid, though in fact there are no columns at all. Could you please help me with this?

On the picture, you can see in the Watch window that myGrid.Columns.Count equals 0

[image: Here you can see in the Watch window that myGrid.Columns.Count equals 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be adding a column which already exists (in the previous datagrid) to another datagrid. The error says that the column exists in the `Columns` collection of **a** datagrid, not neccessarily the one you are trying to add it to

`DataGrid` cannot share columns - you need to remove the column from the previous datagrid. This may mean you have a memory leak somewhere too. If your tab item VM inherits `Screen` you might want to override `OnDeactivate` and clear down the columns

Alternatively, you may be able to get a reference to the parent grid via the column and remove it from it's parent, though I've not used the standard .NET `DataGrid` myself (just used Teleriks one) so I can't be sure - personally though, the clear down on close seems like a cleaner implementation.

It shouldn't be the responsibility of a new instance of a class to clear up after a dead instance, it should be the responsibility of the class to clean up after itself (I keep telling my kids this!)

Comment: Thank you very much. I overrode  OnDeactivate, and that did the trick.